# クリップボードにコピーする方法

Tags: javascript

https://rubygems.org/gems/i18n/versions/0.7.0

こちらのサイトの右側にテキストをクリップボードにコピーするボタンがあります。

htmlを覗いてみるとdata属性に対象の文字がありますが、どうやってコピーさせてるのでしょうか?

JavaScriptで可能なのでしょうか?

Answer (score 11):

Javascript からのコピー＆ペーストの機能は用意されてはいますが、全てのブラウザで一貫して動くことがない手法になっています。クリップボードはユーザが使用するローカルのアプリケーション間で共有されますので、Webページがクリップボードを参照・変更できると、ユーザの作業内容がWebページのスクリプトを通じて漏えいする危険があります。そのため、Webページからのクリップボードの操作は厳しく制限されています。各ブラウザはクリップボードを参照・変更する API を有していますが、 特別な権限を必要とする上、バージョンによっても、APIの使用制限が違うため、安定したクリップボードの扱いができないのが現状です。

[rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/i18n/versions/0.7.0) のサイトのソース見ると、ライブラリとしては [zeroclipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard)を使用していることが確認できます。これは、ページ上に表示されない Flash コンテンツを起動し、 Flash の API 経由でコピー機能を実現しているものです。

Javascipt からクリップボードを扱う API は W3C から [Clipboard API and events](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/) としてワーキングドラフトが出されています。仕組みとしては、ユーザーがコピー＆ペースト操作をした際に、イベントハンドラで Clipboard の中身を参照する形になります。ユーザーが、Webページに対してコピー＆ペースト操作した時だけ、セキュリティ制限解除としているわけです。しかしこの API は、現在普及しているブラウザのなかでも [Firefox が十分にサポート](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent)するのみです。全てのブラウザでサポートがされている訳ではありません。

セキュリティが厳しく、ブラウザによって機能が安定しないため、コピー＆ペーストを行うために、 Javascript ではなく Flash のコピー＆ペースト機能を使うことが主流になりました。[zeroclipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard) がはやりだしたのは、 [GitHub が使いだしてから](https://github.com/blog/1365-a-more-transparent-clipboard-button)だったと記憶しています。以前はたしか[これ](https://github.com/mojombo/clippy)を使っていました。Flash でも、コピー＆ペーストの権限を得る瞬間が [ユーザのコピー＆ペースト操作または、ボタンのクリックの瞬間である必要](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html)があります。よってあのようなコピーボタンでの実装になっているわけです。

Answer (score 6):

そのページに関しては、[**zeroclipboard**](http://zeroclipboard.org/) を使用していますね。
指定はJavascriptで行われていますけど、内部ではFlashが利用されていますね。

https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard

こちらの利用方法サンプルのHTMLにも`data-clipboard-text`が指定されています。
ここに指定しているテキストがコピーされます。

`data-clipboard-target`属性で別のタグの内容をコピーさせることもできます。
（[最初のリンク先](http://zeroclipboard.org/) で Textareaの内容がコピーされるのはそのためです。）

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="copy-button" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!" title="Click to copy me.">Copy to Clipboard</button>
    <script src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```